# How do I evaluate an ubuntu OS upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I am using a 2012 macbook pro as my personal laptop, I was using ubuntu 18 LTS, and recently the software update GUI has been informing me that ubuntu 20 LTS is out. I did a back up of my data before starting the upgrade, and then kicked off the process.

Right at the end I was told that a basic package had failed to install, and the upgrade would be terminated, and my system might be unstable.

I'm unsure what to make of this. When I look at my system info, it says i'm running ubuntu 20 LTS, and the system seems to be relatively functional. The look of the OS seems to have updated to the new version, and most thing seem to be working. Some of the apps I used to have installed from 3rd party sources, didn't survive the upgrade, but otherwise things seem okay for now.

I was wondering if there was a way to evaluate the quality/health of my system, other than just using it until it either breaks, or thrives?

Comment: If you can remember something of what the basic package was, it can help.  All upgrades disable/remove PPAs, you should do this yourself before upgrade.  Having a good 20.04 ISO on a USB might be a good idea to have before needing it.

Comment: If your upgrade failed half-way you need to do a clean install.  A half-installed system is going to break - there's almost no way to gauge *how* it'll break but if the upgrade was terminated and halted mid-process you're in a 'half-upgraded' state and there's no real way to evaluate the 'health' of the system - it's 'half upgraded' and likely to break.

Comment: The basic package it said it failed to install was definitely a text editor, it will have been nano or vim or something like that. I'll make a clean 20 LTS USB to use if things get dicey, I suppose one question is: i've made a backup of my 18.04 ubuntu, will I be able to restore to that backup after I've done a fresh install of 20 LTS?